# Python requests throws SSLCertVerificationError with Let's Encrypt certificates

Tags: python-requests, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

While executing the following code in Python 3.8

```
import requests
requests.get("https://e-sat.de/")
```

I get this error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='e-sat.de',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1131)')))

However, if I access the website with my browser, everything seems to be fine with the certificate.
I am now wondering, why this happens.
I already tried to use the CABundle from https://certifiio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

```
import requests
requests.get("https://e-sat.de/", verify="path/to/certs.pem")
```

The same happens for several websites. All of them have Let's Encrpyt certificates. Is this related to that?
I am not able to include every single certificate of a website manually as they dynamically change.

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to disable the certification check using `verify=False` for this specific problem? You might also be better of opening a issue for requests on github.

Comment: The problem is that this is used in a webcrawler that is supposed to detect broken links. This also should include websites where SSL is not setup properly (where this is a valid error). By using verify=False it would also ignore those cases. Also, this would be only a workaround and not really solve the problem.

Comment: @orangenhaft, have you managed to solve your problem? Today I faced exactly the same behavior with another site with Let's Encrypt certificate. The site worked for me before and https://crt.sh/ database shows they updated the certificate a couple of weeks ago. So it is definitely certificate related. But browser works fine, only python have problem. I checked and see that my python-certifi package was updated yesterday - so it appears to be up to date also.

Comment: As of now it looks like a known issue for me... https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi/pull/162 But solution isn't clear.

Answer (score -1):

In order for the certificate to be verified, it must be issued correctly

```
sudo certbot certonly --rsa-key-size 2048 --preferred-challenges http-01 --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos --email your_email@exaple.com -d example.com
```

The `sudo certbot certonly` command launches the Cure bat utility to get a new certificate.

The parameter `--rsa-key-size 2048` indicates the use of an RSA key with a length of 2048 bits.

The `--preferred-challenges http-01` parameter indicates the use of the domain ownership verification method via HTTP-01.

The `--server parameter https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`  indicates the use of the Let's Encrypt API v2 server.

The `--agree-tos` parameter indicates acceptance of the terms of use of Let's Encrypt.

Parameter `--email your_email@example.com`  indicates the email address that will be used to contact the domain owner.

Parameter `-d example.com`  indicates the domain name for which a new certificate will be requested.